# React - onChange event & function not working on imported Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have the following code/components. The onChange event on the imported Input component is not working, it doesn't get triggered. I have tried different solutions on the web but they don't work.
However, If I try to render an  element directly in the APP function rather than importing an external component, it works. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

- Input component

  ```
  import React from "react";

   export default function Input(event) {
      return <input />;
    }
  ```
- Item component

  ```
  import React from 'react';
   export default function Item({text}) {
        console.log({text});
        return <li>{text}</li>
    }
  ```
- App.JS

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Input from "./input";
import Item from "./item";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();

  function handleChange(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setText(event.target.value);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>JSX will go here!</h1>
      <Input onChange={ event => handleChange(event)} />
      <Item text={text} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Folder structure:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0WDp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You passed that as a prop. Item component should be

```
 export default function Input(props) {
    return <input onChange={props.onChange}/>;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Remember to pass the prop into the `<input />` element

```
function Welcome(props) {
    return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Welcome name="Sara" />
            <Welcome name="Cahal" />      
            <Welcome name="Edite" />    
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: While the link to the docs is helpful, it would be more helpful to show their code with changes to accept the needed prop rather than showing the code from the docs.